# When are Firebase Security Rules needed for database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am creating an application with React Native that uses the Real Time Database from Firebase. 
As you may know, there are rules that you can modify to make your app more secure (for example, that users can only write if authenticated and so on).

Right now I am only testing the app so the rules are these:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

My question is:

If I don't change them when I launch to production, do I have a risk to get hacked? (Data deleted, changed...).

I don't have authentication at the moment, so no user data could be stolen, and the data inside the app won't be confidential. Do I still need the protection?

I am worried that some hacker is bored somewhere and decides to erase my entire database for fun, or worse, change image URL's to obscene pictures.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I don't change them when I launch to production, do I have a risk to get hacked?

Absolutely, yes.  Your rules allow anyone with an internet connection to read and write anything in your database, without trace.  This has been known to happen.

Comment: Thanks, authentication is the way to prevent it right?

Comment: If you use it along with security rules that correctly express the limitations you want for each user.

Comment: I **highly** recommend studying https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules